# Two equations in one line

Tags: equations

How can I write these two equations in a single row:

```
∀i,j 1≤i,j≤n and cij = ∑ aikbkj
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is quite straightforward with the `align` or `alignat` environment

Answer (score 14):

Even ordinary `equation` enable to write two equation in the same row (transcribed in classic math notation):

```
\begin{equation}
\forall i,j:\ 1\leq i,j\leq n
   \quad\mathrm{and}\quad 
c_{ij} = \sum a_{ik} b_{kj}
\end{equation}
```

where with `\mathrm` is mimic surrounding text font. In this case, both equation will have common number. Without equation numbering just use `equation*` or `\[ ... \]`.

With package `amsmath` or `mathtools` you can write:

```
\documentclass{article
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\forall i,j 1\leq i,j\leq n 
   \quad\text{and}\quad 
c_{ij} = \sum a_{ik} b_{kj}
\end{equation}
or if you liked
    \begin{equation}
\forall i,j:\ 1\leq i,j\leq n
   \text{ and }
c_{ij} = \sum a_{ik} b_{kj}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

or use math environments, which are defined by `amsmath` or `mathtools`. For example: `gather`. In this case you can use `\text{ ...}` which for text use font from main text together with spaces (what `mathrm` not).

In the case, that those equations is in the text, than seems to be naturally to write (split them into two math expression):

`some text $\forall i,j:\ 1\leq i,j\leq n$ and $c_{ij} = \sum a_{ik} b_{kj}$ some more text`

Comment: I wouldn't use `\mathrm` for text *and*.

Comment: @Sigur, see upgrade of my answer. Personally I always use package `mathtools` and `\text{ ... }`. So the first example only show what you can do, if for some reason you don't use `amsmath` or `mathtools` package.

Answer (score 4):

First, without proper UTF support, the compiler is going to choke on the suggested input (or at least omit some symbols). Assuming that you want pdfLaTeX to do the job, you rewrite those symbols using LaTeX conventions. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
You have $\forall i,j\quad 1\le i, j\le n$ and $c_{ij} = \sum a_{ik} b_{kj}$, but consider this:
\[
\forall i,j\quad 1\le i, j\le n \quad \text{and} \quad c_{ij} = \sum a_{ik} b_{kj}
\]
There goes the rest of your text.
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Output with two equations]

Note the difference in the size of the summation symbol in inline (`$formula$`) and displayed (`\[formula\]`) math.

If the space seems too wide to you, you can change the `\quad` command into a simple escaped space `\ ​`. The [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package is required to typeset proper text in math mode (spaces are not being ignored etc., unlike the suggested solutions with `\mathrm{and}` that does not require the aforementioned package but still treats the text as roman symbols in math mode).

You might want to separate those lower indices with a semicolon (like `a_{i;j}`) because in some fields (like panel data analysis) it is quite unclear whether `a_{2t-1}` means “`a` at period (2t−1)” or “`a_2` at period (t−1)”, so this is not just a matter of æsthetics.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the equation in a inline-mode, then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

$ \forall i,j \text{ } 1\leq i,j\leq n \text{ and } c_{ij} = \sum{a_{ik} b_{kj}} $

\end{document}
```